# unable to make AJAX call from jsPDF fromHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, jspdf

I have a simple structure that generates a PDF from jsPDF, gets the 'datauristring' and passes that into an AJAX request. However, the AJAX method doesn't fire. When it tries to 'send' it throws an exception 'h is undefined'. I figured that out from tracing the XHR requests and that appears in the jQuery lib. Can I not fire the AJAX request so soon after the callback from jsPDF?

I should note i'm sending the PDF to a service that is combining that pdf with another and returning a brand new document.

```
var docX = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");
margins = {
    top: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20,
    width: 522
};
specialElementHandlers = {
  // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
  '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
      // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
      return true
  }
};
docX.fromHTML (
    document.getElementById('productModalContent'),
    margins.left,
    margins.top, {
        'width' : margins.width,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function (dispose) {
        specDoc = (docX.output('datauristring'));
        console.log(dispose);
        //docX.save('asdfas.pdf');
        //console.log(specDoc);
        processPDF(specDoc);
    }, margins
);  
function processPDF(doc) {
  console.log(doc.length);

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://someurl",
      data: {
          'partNumber' : '$!{rawPartNumber}',
          'region' : '$!{regionContentlet.code}',
          'doc' : doc
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log("success?");
          var link=document.createElement('a');
          link.href='data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
          link.download="myfile.pdf";
          link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          link.click();
      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log(data); 
      }
  });
```

}

EDIT: remove ajax and added fetch.

```
const response = await fetch('myurl', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            'partNumber' : '$!{rawPartNumber}',
            'region' : '$!{regionContentlet.code}',
            'myDiv' : doc
        }
    });
```

Comment: At first look, the only places I can find the variable `h` inside the jsPDF lib, is inside the rect and rectRounded functions. It would make sense that this is called by fromHTML() somewhere inside the render function. When I look at the source of fromHTML() https://github.com/willowsystems/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js however, it only accepts 4 parameters, not 6. So which version of jsPDF are you using? Since if you expected 6 parameters, I'm probably looking at the wrong lib or your function processPDF is not used at all.

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script> is the version i'm using. No I think that 'h is undefined' is actually in the jquery lib

Comment: Do you get `console.log("success?");` or `console.log(data);` or do you get the error before that? Have you tried using a fetch() request instead of jquery to avoid the problem?

Comment: None of those show up, which is weird. It's like jQuery isn't bubbling it up. I haven't tried fetch yet

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I copied your code into the <script> tags of a otherwise empty html page. I loaded jquery ( 3.4.1 ) from google and jspdf through the link you provided. I see the ajax request being made. Once it goes into timeout, I get the jquery error handler getting triggered. Have you checked that the response from the server is correct if you don't use jquery? We might be looking at the wrong part of the app.

Comment: If I remove the HTML element with the id `productModalContent`, I get nothing anymore. No console.log of the length, no ajax call, no error. No feedback from fromHTML() at all, while it clearly fails. I assume that you already checked that the modal can still be found and that `document.getElementById('productModalContent')` is not null?

Comment: Yup, it's definitely still there. I even dump the length of string in processPDF and I get a positive value (66k or so) which tells me the data is reaching that function. It's just the AJAX that is dying out. I tried fetch with some success as in it at least hits my backend server. The data didn't arrive though. Probably my fetch request is wrong

Comment: Then I fear I'm done. I cannot reproduce the `h is undefined` error, even when using `$.ajax()`. I do get cors errors, but those should trigger your error callback. And they disappear once I add the corrrect cors settings for my own machine.

Comment: No worries. I'll take all your advice and keep at it. I'm sure you've identified part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might stop by this question, I did solve my issue. I wasn't able to get the AJAX call to work from within jsPDF's fromHTML function. I ended up getting the first PDF as a base64 string, then calling the jsPDF's fromHTML for the second PDF set of data and finally using pdf-lib to stitch the two PDFs together all in js.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>

async function processPDF() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'mypdfurl',
        data: {

        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success?");
            var docX = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");
                margins = {
                top: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 20,
                width: 575,             
                };
                specialElementHandlers = {
                    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                        return true
                    },
                    '.info': function (element, renderer) {
                        element.style.fontSize = "12px";
                    },
                    '.spec': function (element, renderer) {
                        element.style.fontSize = "12px";
                    },
                    '.attribute': function (element, renderer) {
                        element.style.fontSize = "12px";
                    },
                    '#logoProductPrint': function(element, renderer) {
                        var ele = element.firstElementChild;
                        ele.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;height:50px");                            
                    },

                };
            var itm = document.getElementById('productPrint');
            var itm_p = itm.cloneNode(true);
            synchronizeCssStyles(itm, itm_p, true);

            docX.fromHTML (
                //document.getElementById('productPrint'),
                itm_p,
                margins.left,
                margins.top, 
                {
                    'width' : margins.width,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
                },
                async function (dispose) {
                    var specDoc = (docX.output('datauristring'));

                    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
                    var d = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
                    const firstDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(d);
                    const secondDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(specDoc);

                    const firstPage = await pdfDoc.copyPages(firstDoc, [0]);
                    pdfDoc.addPage(firstPage[0]);
                    const secondPage = await pdfDoc.copyPages(secondDoc, [0]);

                    pdfDoc.addPage(secondPage[0]);
                    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();


                    const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    var link=document.createElement('a');
                    link.href=blobUrl;

                    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    link.click();

                }, margins
            );     


        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        }
    });

    function synchronizeCssStyles(src, destination, recursively) {

    // if recursively = true, then we assume the src dom structure and destination dom structure are identical (ie: cloneNode was used)

    // window.getComputedStyle vs document.defaultView.getComputedStyle 
    // @TBD: also check for compatibility on IE/Edge 
    destination.style.cssText = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(src, "").cssText;

    if (recursively) {
        var vSrcElements = src.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var vDstElements = destination.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (var i = vSrcElements.length; i--;) {
            var vSrcElement = vSrcElements[i];
            var vDstElement = vDstElements[i];
//          console.log(i + " >> " + vSrcElement + " :: " + vDstElement);
            vDstElement.style.cssText = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(vSrcElement, "").cssText;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you can't use the first approch is b/c you have to fetch it as a blob, so that jQuery nor xhr dose not try to encode binary data into text. That way you will get corrupt data.
You need to get it as raw data. jQuery is bad at this b/c you can't change the `responsetype` to be a blob. so you need to write the xhr request yourself or use the fetch api `fetch(url).then(r => r.blob()).then(code)`

but if i where you i whould have reverted back from base64 to raw binary to save data and used a (perhaps hidden) `<from method="https://someurl" hidden>` to download the pdf using correct response headers

Comment: I tried fetch requests as well and it still didn't work right. I did get different behavior but the PDF data I was sending the pdf data from jsPDF to by backend, it wasn't populated. Sorry this isn't a good explanation.  Interesting point on the raw binary data I didn't try that. Thank you.